# Gnuradio package annoyance

Tags: dpkg, gnuradio

I am using [Xu|U]buntu 18.04 LTS updated from the Ubuntu repositories, and there is an annoyance that I didn't find a place to report other than this.  Hope it is ok to do it here.

In the package:

ii  gnuradio       3.7.11-10    amd64        GNU Radio Software Radio Toolkit

There is a file '/usr/share/mime/packages/gnuradio.xml' that is not a proper XML file.  Its contents is a single line containing:

/usr/share/gnuradio/grc/freedesktop/gnuradio-grc.xml

Every time any package is installed or updated I get the message:

`/usr/share/mime/packages/gnuradio.xml:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found
/usr/share/gnuradio/grc/freedesktop/gnuradio-grc.xml
^
Failed to parse '/usr/share/mime/packages/gnuradio.xml'`

It is not a show stopper or anything like that, but looks a lot like a sloppy maintenance in the package.

HTH

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a question.  There should be bug reporting channels specific to gnuradio (on its git repository, for instance).

Answer (score 2):

It is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnuradio/+bug/1769432)

Try the workaround, from there.  `sudo rm /usr/share/mime/packages/gnuradio.xml`

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/gnuradio/grc/freedesktop/gnuradio-grc.xml /usr/share/mime/packages/gnuradio.xml
```

Comment: I understand your point, and I am sure it will remove the error message.   If I just remove the file it will remove the error message as well.

My doubt is how could it affect the installation of an update of the package, if I substitute a file by a symlink, just copy the linked one or just remove the file.